# React Native: Images positioning to the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, css-position, image-resizing

I have two images that i want to wrapped in a row and I want to put it in the top of the screen.

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.topWrapper}>
        <Image source={TOP_START_GRAPHIC} style={styles.topStartImage} />
        <Image source={TOP_END_GRAPHIC} style={styles.topEndImage} />
      </View>
      // another contents goes here...
    </View>
    </View>
```

here is the styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  imgBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
  },

  topWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
  }, 
  topStartImage: {
    width: screen.width * 0.6,
    height: screen.height * 0.4,
    resizeMode: "contain",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    alignContent: "flex-start",
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 2,
  },
  topEndImage: {
    right: 0,
    width: screen.width * 0.45,
    height: screen.height * 0.6,
    resizeMode: "contain",
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    alignContent: "flex-start",
  },
})
```

I set backgroundColor to check the space of each image but I found out that the image is on the center of that space. I expect it to be in the top of the screen and I already set the content and items alignment to be in the top (using 'flex-start') but it still not working.

**//EDITED:**

this is what I see:
[reality :'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzYC5.png)

what I expected:
[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WMWT.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: could you share a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Could you also post what would you like to see? The end result

Comment: please kindly check my updatee

Comment: I just can't try it fully without all the codes. Can you provide the full code? for this page

Comment: Agree with @BalaVigness having a sandbox would be great. Do you think you can create one on codesandbox.io?

Answer (score 0):

The `resizeMode: "contain"` makes the images in center of the space. I just removed it and made the topWrapper to be absolute (so it sticks to the top).

```
topWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    position:"absolute"
  }, 
  topStartImage: {
    width: screen.width * 0.6,
    height: screen.height * 0.4,
    zIndex: 2,
  },
  topEndImage: {
    width: screen.width * 0.4,
    height: screen.height * 0.6,
    zIndex: 1,
  }
```

If it is still not ok, just reach me.

<sub>upvote makes me happy :)</sub>

Comment: hi, thank you for trying it! I already tried your solution but I found out that the image become super zoomed and seems like the image is being cropped :' (for example: in the second image I can't see the red rectangle) I need to get the full image, but in the size of width and height I mentioned above.